# Installation help (ERROR: configuring bootloader error: command failed with exit status; exit status: 1)

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, grub

I'm trying to install EOS 6.1 as a dual boot alongside Windows10 on my laptop. I've already space on my SSD for EOS; I have 40GB formatted ext4 for root, 8GB for swap, and about 140GB ext4 for home.

I used the custom install option, and set the root, swap, and home on the respective partitions (sda7, sda8, sda9). Looks like my sda2 is where the efi system partition is; it was initially 256MB, I expanded that to ~540MB before starting the installation (it is flagged as esp and boot on gparted). Since there was no option to "use" this partition as efi/esp, I didn't touch it, thinking EOS would detect it automatically. However, I'm running in to this error:

```
INFO: starting configuring bootloader step  
INFO: /dev/sda: installing bootloader for Bios  
INFO: running "chroot" "/tmp/distinst. oGEQDhAu7C3P"  
"grub-install" "--recheck" "--target=1386-pc" "/dev/sda"  
WARN: Installing for 1386-pc platform.  
WARN: grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be
possible.  
WARN: grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..  
WARN: grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.  
ERROR: configuring bootloader error: command failed with exit status; exit status: 1  
ERROR: errored while installing system: command failed with exit status: exit status: 1  
INFO: Install error: command failed with exit status: exit status: 1
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've disabled secure boot and enabled legacy boot so that I can boot from the usb. Win10 continues to load fine.
My Win10 partition is sda3, and sda4 through sda6 are system recovery partitions; didn't touch them. My system is a Intel Core i5, with a 16GB ram, and 512GB SSD.

Any help much appreciated! I'm not a very tech-savvy user. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, two things helped: one, formatting the usb with gpt (rufus was defaulting to mbr); two, using a different usb drive.